# Console.WriteLine correctly handle null string

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Just find that `Console.WriteLine` can handle `null` string correctly 
like `Console.WriteLine((string)null)`;

Can I assume that most class library handle null reference correctly?

Comment: Btw, in the case you describe, what _handling null correctly_ means? Writing 'null' or ''?

Comment: nice, three answers, Yes, No, and Maybe. :)

Comment: @jb - May the best man win :).

Comment: If you want to show "null" as a string you can just use `string test = null ?? "null";`.

Comment: @Gucu112: You probably meant `string test = test ?? "null";`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... Yes.

You can expect that (almost) all classes will handle null references correctly.

However, I feel that what you mean by "correctly" is not the same as what the author of the class means.

For instance, if you try to open a file and pass `null` for the path to the file to open, it will not fail silently, it will throw an exception.

If that is what you mean by "handle correctly", then sure. In fact, I hope all classes handles null references correctly.

But don't expect the program to just trundle on as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 10):

**No.**

This fully depends on the method you call. See the MSDN documentation per method on what to expect when you pass a `null`.

It's never safe to make assumptions about `null` when calling into someone else's API or library, especially if you don't have its source code to use as a reference. Always read the docs. And if the docs don't say, code defensively.

However, the library methods are programmed in such a manner that when they do not accept a `null`, they will throw an exception telling you that it's not a valid argument.

Comment: Right.  It's never safe to make assumptions about null when calling into someone else's API or library, especially if you don't have its  source code to use as a reference.  Always read the docs.  And if the docs don't say, code defensively.

Comment: @Mike Clark - Exactly. Thanks for the addition, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on what you mean by "correctly" and on the method itself. Unless you mean "could throw an exception because it was expecting an actual string", then no.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when the argument (doesn't matter if string or any other type) is required to do something the method will usually crash with exception when that argument is null.

Couple of examples:

1. Files.. can't open "null" file, so --> error.
2. Parse --> can't parse "null", so --> error. (Yeah, they added TryParse in 2.0)

On the other hand, when the argument is not required the method will usually "swallow the frog" when it's null and treat it as some default value, for example empty string.
In the case of WriteLine method of the Console object, it doesn't really *need* the string, it simply write it to the console so it doesn't care if it's null.

So like others here said, it depends on what method you try to use and you better read before trying to pass null values.